# Is there a way to selectively override standard theorem labeling *with* cleveref and hyperref support?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, amsthm

I have the following problem:

- Document with many different 'types' of theorem, e.g., "theorem", "lemma", "proposition", etc. These are defined in the usual (`amsthm`) way using environments `kttheorem`, `ktlemma`, `ktprop`, etc.
- In the document proper (not the appendix), suppose chapter 5 contains two theorems: a proposition with label `pugsrcute` and a theorem with label `pugsrsmart`. When the document is compiled, these happen to be called Prop. 5.1 and Theorem 5.2 respectively.
- The proof of `pugsrcute` happens to be quite long and refers to a supporting lemma and a supporting proposition. As a result, the proof of `pugsrcute` *as well as* the supporting theorems are placed in the appendix.
- In the appendix, ideally I'd like to be able to insert the following:

  ```
  \begin{supportfor}{pugsrsmart}
      \begin{ktlemma}
          \label{pugsrsmall}
          ...
      \end{ktlemma}

      \begin{ktprop}
          \label{smalldogsrcute}
          ...
      \end{ktprop}
  \end{supportfor}
  ```

  and have the theorem environments inside `supportfor` behave normally in all respects *except that* instead of using the standard numbering scheme, the theorems appear as "Lemma 5.1(a)" and "Proposition 5.1(b)", where 5.1 is the number of label `pugsrsmart` and where "a" and "b" are the first two letters in alphabetic sequence.
- The `\cref`s to `pugsrsmall` and `smalldogsrcute` would likewise expand to values that respect this alternate numbering scheme, with proper hyperlinks. Hence, `\cref{pugsrsmall}` would expand to "Lemma 5.1(a)" with "5.1(a)" hyperlinked, and `\cref{smalldogsrcute}` would expand to "Prop. 5.1(b)", with "5.1(b)" hyperlinked.

### Question

Is selective overriding of theorem labeling in this way possible?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[
    colorlinks,
    final,
    hyperfootnotes = false,
    linkcolor      = blue,
    citecolor      = blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

% environments for theorems and lemmas
\NewDocumentCommand{\ktnewtheorem}{ommm}{  % \ktnewtheorem[usecounter]{type}{Long}{short}
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
        {\newtheorem {#2} {#3} [section]}
        {\newtheorem {#2} [#1] {#3}}

    \crefname {#2} {#4} {\MakeLowercase{#3}}
    \Crefname {#2} {#4} {#3}
}

\ktnewtheorem            {kttheorem} {Theorem}     {Theorem}
\ktnewtheorem[kttheorem] {ktlemma}   {Lemma}       {Lemma}
\ktnewtheorem[kttheorem] {ktprop}    {Proposition} {Prop.}
\ktnewtheorem[kttheorem] {ktcor}     {Corollary}   {Cor.}

% ktrestate (restate theorem/proposition/lemma/etc.) environment
\newenvironment {ktrestate} [2] [0pt]
    {\vspace{#1}\noindent\textbf{\Cref{#2}.}\hspace{2pt}\begingroup\em}
    {\endgroup}

% placeholder \supportfor{label}; magic should happen here!
\newenvironment {supportfor} [1]
    {\begingroup}
    {\endgroup}


\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{4}
\section{Pugs}

The following \namecrefs{pugsrcute} was first proved by Leonhard Euler in 1760.

\begin{ktprop}
    \label{pugsrcute}
    Let $c_{\mathrm{pug}}$ be the cuteness factor of a pug.
    Then $c_{\mathrm{pug}} \geq 8\pi^{-1}$ a.s.
\end{ktprop}
\begin{proof}
    See \cref{pugproofs} for proof.
\end{proof}

\noindent Euler hit another home run in 1762.

\begin{kttheorem}
    \label{pugsrsmart}
    Let $P$ be a pug. Then $P$ is as least as intelligent as an Artin representation
    of degree $2$.
\end{kttheorem}
\begin{proof}
    The result follows logically from the fact that abelian L-functions are
    meromorphic for non-trivial characters, and $P$ looks kind of like an L-function
    if you squint really hard.
\end{proof}


\newpage
\section{Appendix}
\label{pugproofs}

First, we prove some supporting results.

\begin{supportfor}{pugsrcute}
    \begin{ktlemma} % Currently "Lemma 6.1"; Should be "Lemma 5.1(a)"
        \label{pugsrsmall}
        Pugs are small.
    \end{ktlemma}
    \begin{proof}
        Just look at them.
    \end{proof}

    \begin{ktprop} % Currently "Proposition 6.2"; Should be "Proposition 5.1(b)"
        \label{smalldogsrcute}
        Small dogs are cute.
    \end{ktprop}
    \begin{proof}
        The result follows from Fermat's celebrated treatise ``On the Adorableness of
        Dogs and Other Small Mammals''.
    \end{proof}
\end{supportfor}

% The following \cref currently expands to "Lemma 6.1 and Prop 6.2". NO!
% Should expand to "Lemma 5.1(a) and Prop. 5.1(b)"!
\noindent Now, we use \cref{pugsrsmall,smalldogsrcute} in the proof of \cref{pugsrcute}.

\begin{ktrestate}[3mm]{pugsrcute}
    Let $c_{\mathrm{pug}}$ be the cuteness factor of a pug.
    Then $c_{\mathrm{pug}} \geq 8\pi^{-1}$ a.s.
\end{ktrestate}
\begin{proof}
    % The following \cref's expand to "Lemma 6.1" and "Prop 6.2". NO!
    % Should expand to "Lemma 5.1(a)" and "Prop 5.1(b)".
    The result follows from \cref{pugsrsmall}, mixed with \cref{smalldogsrcute},
    baked at $350^\circ$ for $25$ minutes, and seasoned to taste.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

### Added: Best I Can Do

The following is the best solution I've come up with this far. The compiled document looks right, but there are a number of problems identified in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[
    colorlinks,
    final,
    hyperfootnotes = false,
    linkcolor      = blue,
    citecolor      = blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

% environments for theorems and lemmas
\NewDocumentCommand{\ktnewtheorem}{ommm}{  % \ktnewtheorem[usecounter]{type}{Long}{short}
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
        {\newtheorem {#2} {#3} [section]}
        {\newtheorem {#2} [#1] {#3}}

    \crefname {#2} {#4} {\MakeLowercase{#3}}
    \Crefname {#2} {#4} {#3}
    %% ADDED
    \expandafter\def\csname #2Long\endcsname{#3}
    \expandafter\def\csname #2long\endcsname{\MakeLowercase{#3}}
    \expandafter\def\csname #2short\endcsname{#4}
    %% END ADDED
}

\ktnewtheorem            {kttheorem} {Theorem}     {Theorem}
\ktnewtheorem[kttheorem] {ktlemma}   {Lemma}       {Lemma}
\ktnewtheorem[kttheorem] {ktprop}    {Proposition} {Prop.}
\ktnewtheorem[kttheorem] {ktcor}     {Corollary}   {Cor.}

% ktrestate (restate theorem/proposition/lemma/etc.) environment
\newenvironment {ktrestate} [2] [0pt]
    {\vspace{#1}\noindent\textbf{\Cref{#2}.}\hspace{2pt}\begingroup\em}
    {\endgroup}

% placeholder \supportfor{label}; magic should happen here!
\newenvironment {supportfor} [1]
    {\begingroup}
    {\endgroup}

%% BEST I CAN DO
% Problems:
%  - Uses \begin{ktsuppthm}{theoremenv}{label}{extension} rather than the desired
%       \begin{supportfor}{label}
%          \begin{theoremenv}
%    syntax.
%  - Requires all supplemental theorems to be declared in advance (i.e. in document
%    preamble).
%  - Requires proof definitions to specify their extension rather than assigning
%    them automatically.
%  - Requires writing to the .aux file, and is generally hackish.
%  - Version below only supports supplemental theorems for ONE theorem. Support for
%    more would be even messier.

\makeatletter
\def\csxdefaux#1#2{%
    \protected@write\@mainaux{}{%
        \csgdef{\detokenize{#1}}{#2}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand* {\ktdefsuppthm} [1] {
    \expandafter\gdef\csname ktsuppthmext#1\endcsname{?}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname ktsuppthmshort#1\endcsname{?}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname ktsuppthmlong#1\endcsname{?}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname ktsuppthmLong#1\endcsname{?}
    \crefname {ktsuppthm#1} {\csname ktsuppthmshort#1\endcsname} {\csname ktsuppthmlong#1\endcsname}
    \Crefname {ktsuppthm#1} {\csname ktsuppthmshort#1\endcsname} {\csname ktsuppthmLong#1\endcsname}
    \creflabelformat {ktsuppthm#1} {\hyperlink
        {L\csname ktsuppthmext#1\endcsname.#1}
        {\labelcref*{\csname ktsuppthmext#1\endcsname}(#1)}}

    \expandafter\newcommand \csname supplabel#1\endcsname [2] {%  \supplabel<x> {type} {label}
        \raisebox{12pt}{\hypertarget {L##2.#1} {}}%
        \csxdefaux{ktsuppthmext#1}{##2}%
        \csxdefaux{ktsuppthmshort#1}{\csname ##1short\endcsname}%
        \csxdefaux{ktsuppthmlong#1}{\csname ##1long\endcsname}%
        \csxdefaux{ktsuppthmLong#1}{\csname ##1Long\endcsname}%
        \expandafter\gdef\csname ktsuppthmext#1\endcsname{##2}%
        \expandafter\gdef\csname ktsuppthmshort#1\endcsname{\csname ##1short\endcsname}%
        \expandafter\gdef\csname ktsuppthmlong#1\endcsname{\csname ##1long\endcsname}%
        \expandafter\gdef\csname ktsuppthmLong#1\endcsname{\csname ##1Long\endcsname}%
        \label[ktsuppthm#1]{##2.#1}%
    }
}

\ktdefsuppthm{a}
\ktdefsuppthm{b}

\newenvironment {ktsuppthm} [4] [0pt]  % ktsuppthm [leadvspc]{type}{label}{ext}
    {%
        \vspace{#1}\noindent\csname supplabel#4\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
        \textbf{\csname #2Long\endcsname~\labelcref*{#3}(#4).}\hspace{5pt}\begingroup\em%
    }
    {\endgroup}
%% END BEST I CAN DO


\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{4}
\section{Pugs}

The following \namecrefs{pugsrcute} was first proved by Leonhard Euler in 1760.

\begin{ktprop}
    \label{pugsrcute}
    Let $c_{\mathrm{pug}}$ be the cuteness factor of a pug.
    Then $c_{\mathrm{pug}} \geq 8\pi^{-1}$ a.s.
\end{ktprop}
\begin{proof}
    See \cref{pugproofs} for proof.
\end{proof}

\noindent Euler hit another home run in 1762.

\begin{kttheorem}
    \label{pugsrsmart}
    Let $P$ be a pug. Then $P$ is as least as intelligent as an Artin representation
    of degree $2$.
\end{kttheorem}
\begin{proof}
    The result follows logically from the fact that abelian L-functions are
    meromorphic for non-trivial characters, and $P$ looks kind of like an L-function
    if you squint really hard.
\end{proof}


\newpage
\section{Appendix}
\label{pugproofs}

First, we prove some supporting results.

%\begin{supportfor}{pugsrcute}
    \begin{ktsuppthm}{ktlemma}{pugsrcute}{a}% should be: \begin{ktlemma}
        %\label{pugsrsmall}
        % This implementation automatically makes the label pugsrcute.a.
        Pugs are small.
    \end{ktsuppthm}
    \begin{proof}
        Just look at them.
    \end{proof}

    \begin{ktsuppthm}{ktprop}{pugsrcute}{b}% should be: \begin{ktprop}
        %\label{smalldogsrcute}
        % This implementation automatically makes the label pugsrcute.b.
        Small dogs are cute.
    \end{ktsuppthm}
    \begin{proof}
        The result follows from Fermat's celebrated treatise ``On the Adorableness of
        Dogs and Other Small Mammals''.
    \end{proof}
%\end{supportfor}

% Should expand to "Lemma 5.1(a) and Prop. 5.1(b)".
\noindent Now, we use \cref{pugsrcute.a,pugsrcute.b} in the proof of \cref{pugsrcute}.

\begin{ktrestate}[3mm]{pugsrcute}
    Let $c_{\mathrm{pug}}$ be the cuteness factor of a pug.
    Then $c_{\mathrm{pug}} \geq 8\pi^{-1}$ a.s.
\end{ktrestate}
\begin{proof}
    % Should expand to "Lemma 5.1(a)" and "Prop 5.1(b)".
    The result follows from \cref{pugsrcute.a}, mixed with \cref{pugsrcute.b},
    baked at $350^\circ$ for $25$ minutes, and seasoned to taste.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You asked, "Is selective overriding of theorem labeling ... possible?" Yes. In particular, do take a look at Section 6, entitled "Overriding the cross-reference type", of the user guide of the `cleveref` package. To open the user guide in a pdf viewer, just type `texdoc cleveref` in a command wiindow.

Comment: @Mico: Selective overriding meeting all of these specifications is particularly tricky. I've added "The Best I Can Do" code to the question to show the best solution I've come up with thus far. The resulting compiled document looks and work as required, but a number of problems and hacks are identified in the code, which is why I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
\newenvironment {supportfor} [1]
    {\renewcommand\thekttheorem{\ref{#1}(\alph{kttheorem})}}
    {}
```